# SQL Query - to show all ChairNo's which are available and unavailable

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

Have a small cinema project I've been working on and was hoping for some help on a rather advanced sql query - I'm a complete noob atm.

Comment: `left join` `booki1` and `shows` on `chairs`

Comment: am I not doing that in left join chairs on booki1.SeatNo = Chair.SeatNo ??

Comment: no you are left joining on shows and hence the result.

Comment: can you show me in a query? I'm a very confused noob :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
select SeatNo, 1 as available from Chair where SeatNo in (select SeatNo from Booki1)

Union 

select SeatNo, 0  as available from Chair where SeatNo not in (select SeatNo from Booki1)
```

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer, I am glad that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit confused. The chairs are always there, so it makes no sense to outer-join this table. Have it in the FROM clause instead and outer-join the bookings (or access them in a subquery).

```
select 
  seatno, 
  case when seatno in (select seatno from bookli1 where ddate = ... and ttime = ...) 
  then 0 else 1 end as available
from chair
order by seatno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your left-join should work, but you started with the incorrect table as the basis.  Your CHAIRS (list of all POSSIBLE seats) should be the first table, then LEFT-JOIN to those actually booked.  Left-Join = I want the record from the LEFT (first) table, regardless of a match on the right (second table).

```
select 
      Chair.SeatNo,
      (case when Show.DDate is null then 1 else 0 end) available
   from 
      chair
         left join booki1 
            on Chair.SeatNo = booki1.SeatNo
            left join show
               on booki1.DDate = Show.DDate
              AND booki1.TTime = Show.TTime
              AND booki1.DDate = *insert show id here*;
```

Note, if you only query on the DATE, but not both DATE AND TIME, your "Chair" seat may falsely show as NOT available because it may be occupied at a 6pm showing, but not occupied for a 9pm showing.